# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null

Working with `React` and `styled` component.

I am trying a conditional rendering for a logo. In my react component `<Header>` should only be rendered when there is no logo. Here logo is checked as `companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url` which is from `companies` array.

```
 <HeaderContainer>
        <Header>
          {!companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url &&
            companies[currentCompanyIndex].name}
        </Header>

        {companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url && (
          <Logo
            src={companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url}
            alt={`${companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url}-img`}
          />
        )}
 </HeaderContainer>
```

**Problem** `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null`. In many cases there will only be `name` rendered as header and no logo. So data will be null in many cases. Although I have put the condition, still I get the error. How to handle this issue?

**Expected** Render header only when no logo. When there is logo, ignore header and render logo only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking if `companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo` exists, that why you get this error.

You should have that check both inside Header component and outside (where you render logo)

Answer (score 0):

What you did will only check if logo.url is not undefined. It will not check if it is null.  Edit your code as show below:

```
<HeaderContainer> <Header> {!companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url &&  companies[currentCompanyIndex].name} </Header> {companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url && companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url !== null && ( <Logo src={companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url} alt={`${companies[currentCompanyIndex].logo.url}-img`} /> )} </HeaderContainer>
```

I hope this solves your problem. You also need to check that it is not null apart from being undefined.